# protobuf 2.4.1 - sending data from c++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to exchange messages between c++ and java and vice-versa without success.
I've defined two messages (1 to be sent from c++ to java and another to be sent the other way around) with union types (see attached .proto).

The c++ code is as follows:

```
operational_gui::OperationalMessage message; 
message.set_type(operational_gui::OperationalMessage::OWNPOSITIONREPORT); 
message.mutable_oprep()->set_latitude(38.5); 
message.mutable_oprep()->set_longitude(-9.8); 
message.mutable_oprep()->set_heading(25); 
message.mutable_oprep()->set_validity(0); 

message.SerializeToArray(buf, message.ByteSize()); 
m_pNamedPipeSocket->write(buf, message.ByteSize()); 
m_pNamedPipeSocket->flush();
```

The java code is as follows:

```
int bytes = pipe.read(buffer);

MessagesProtos.OperationalMessage message = MessagesProtos.OperationalMessage.parseFrom(buffer);

switch(message.getType()){
    case OWNPOSITIONREPORT:
        System.out.println("Response is OwnPositionReport");
        break;
    case FRIENDPOSITIONREPORT:
        System.out.println("Response is FriendPositionReport");
        break;
    case COMMSTATUSREPORT:
        System.out.println("Response is CommStatusReport");
        break;
 }
```

The communication is made by pipes (QLocalSocket on c++, FileInputStream on java side)

C++ sends 33 bytes and java received them all but blows with an exception InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).

Any hints ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem requires 4 fields to occur?  Please post self contained minimal compiling examples of your problem.  And post the binary contents of the sent and received message.

Comment: You are absolutely certain that both the Java and C++ message classes have been generated from the same protobuf interface file?  The Java OperationalClass has the same 5 properties as the C++ class?

Comment: What platform is this? On POSIX systems, QLocalSocket creates UNIX domain sockets (`AF_UNIX`), which requires something like [junixsocket](http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/) -- FileInputStream won't work.

Comment: I think willglynn is on the right track, using a real message broker here would probably solve your problems. It is cake to write a quick client for C++ and Java to test it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try Qt Jambi: "[...] In addition, Qt Jambi also enables C++ programmers to easily integrate their Qt code with Java by providing the Qt Jambi generator."

http://qt-jambi.org/

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, you might also consider either [gobjects](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html) or using [DBUS](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) (which also has a Windows port).